# Adding a linked label for a list of features

Tags: c#, oop, linked-list

I have a class that contains a list of features and I would like to add a link label for each item in that list.  When doing this, I am not able to display all of the features, only the first feature.  The smallest code snippet I have is:

```
            foreach (var element in agol.orgServices.services)
            {
                var linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
                linkLabel.Text = element.name + "\n";
                linkLabel.Links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link(i, element.url.Length, element.url));
                i = linkLabel.Text.Length;
                ServicesTab.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
                linkLabel.LinkClicked += (s, z) =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(z.Link.LinkData.ToString());
                    };
            }
```

The results I get are:

[image: What I get]

What I expect to get is something similar to this:

[image: Results I want]

The second image is not individual labels added but a long text string instead. See code snippet below.

```
finalstring += element.name + "\n"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  The link labels were stacking on top of each other so I had to include an increment:

```
int i=0;
            int yi = 30;
            int y = 7;
            int x = 2;

            foreach (var element in agol.orgServices.services)
            {
                var linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
                linkLabel.Name = element.name;
                linkLabel.Text = element.name + "\n";
                linkLabel.Location = new Point(x, y);
                linkLabel.AutoSize = true;
                linkLabel.Links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link(i, element.name.Length, element.url));
                ServicesTab.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
                linkLabel.LinkClicked += (s, z) =>
                    {
                       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(z.Link.LinkData.ToString());
                    };

                y += yi;

                //finalServiceList += element.name + "\n";
            }
```